# How to get a user input value and display another element based on that in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, date, validation

I'm trying to display a checkbox ("I agree"), if for example a user in younger than 18, otherwise not displaying that checkbox.

I wrote a `handleAgreementCheckbox` which should return a boolean (`true`, `false`) if the user is younger than 18, not sure how to get the element value and display the checkbox.

How do I do that in React?

#### Code

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  Form,
  Field
} from 'react-advanced-form'
import {
  Input,
  Button
} from 'react-advanced-form-addons'

export default class RegistrationForm extends React.Component {
  registerUser = ({
    serialized,
    fields,
    form
  }) => {
    return fetch('https://backend.dev', {
      body: JSON.stringify(serialized)
    })
  }

  handleAgreementCheckbox = () => {
      const currentTime = new Date();
      const eligibleUserDOB = new Date(currentTime.getFullYear() - 18, currentTime.getMonth(), currentTime.getDate());
      return currentTime>= eligibleUserDOB;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <section className = "container">
        <Form action = {
          this.registerUser
        }
        onSubmitStart = {
          this.props.onSubmitStart
        }>
            <Input name = "firstName"
            label = "First name"
            required = {
              ({
                get
              }) => {
                return !!get(['lastName', 'value'])
              }
            }/>
            <Input name = "lastName"
            label = "Last name"
            required = {
              ({
                get
              }) => {
                return !!get(['firstName', 'value'])
              }
            }
            />

            <Input name = "emailAddress"
            type = "email"
            label = "Email Address"
            required />

            <Input name = "phoneNumber"
            type = "text"
            label = "Phone Number"
            required />

            <Input name = "dateOfBirth"
            type = "date"
            label = "Date of Birth"
            required />

            <Input name = "eligibleAge"
            type = "checkbox"
            label = "I agree"
            value = "unchecked"
            />
          <Button primary> Submit </Button>
        </Form>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

(Thanks! I'm new to React.)

#### [Demo on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-butterfly-oveqq)

Comment: do you have a working example on codesandbox or stackblitz it will make it easy to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it, Firstly create a state to hold the conditon of true and false of eligibility. Then set that state inside your handleAgreementCheckbox method. Finally use eligibility state to conditionally render the checkbox based on true or false.

```
/**
 * Registration form.
 * The component we have built together as the part of
 * React Advanced Form presentation on Medium.
 */
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form, Field } from "react-advanced-form";
import { Input, Button } from "react-advanced-form-addons";
// import 'react-phone-number-input/style.css'
// import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-number-input'
import PhoneInput from "react-phone-input-2";
import "react-phone-input-2/lib/style.css";

export default class RegistrationForm extends React.Component {
  registerUser = ({ serialized, fields, form }) => {
    return fetch("https://backend.dev", {
      body: JSON.stringify(serialized)
    });
  };

  state = { phone: "", eligible: false };

  handleOnChange = value => {
    console.log(value);
    this.setState({ phone: value }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.phone);
    });
  };

  handleAgreementCheckbox = event => {
    let selectedDate = event.nextValue; //======> fetch selected date and split it to pass into date object.
    selectedDate = selectedDate.split("-");
    console.log(selectedDate);

    const currentTime = new Date();
    const eligibleUserDOB = new Date(
      selectedDate[0],
      selectedDate[1] - 1,
      selectedDate[2]
    );
    console.log(currentTime, eligibleUserDOB);
    console.log(currentTime > eligibleUserDOB);

    if (currentTime >= eligibleUserDOB) { //====> on greater set eligible to true
      this.setState({ eligible: true });
    } else {                              //====> on less set eligible to false
      console.log(this.state);
      this.setState({ eligible: false });
    }

    return currentTime >= eligibleUserDOB;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <section className="container">
        <Form
          action={this.registerUser}
          onSubmitStart={this.props.onSubmitStart}
        >
          <Input
            name="firstName"
            label="First name"
            required={({ get }) => {
              return !!get(["lastName", "value"]);
            }}
          />
          <Input
            name="lastName"
            label="Last name"
            required={({ get }) => {
              return !!get(["firstName", "value"]);
            }}
          />

          <Input
            name="emailAddress"
            type="email"
            label="Email Address"
            required
          />

          <PhoneInput
            name="phoneNumber"
            type="text"
            country={"us"}
            enableAreaCodes={true}
            onlyCountries={["us"]}
            areaCodes={{ us: ["332"] }}
            inputProps={{
              name: "phone",
              country: "us",
              required: true,
              autoFocus: true
            }}
            value={this.state.phone}
            onChange={this.handleOnChange}
            required
          />

          <Input
            name="dateOfBirth"
            type="date"
            label="Date of Birth"
            onChange={this.handleAgreementCheckbox}
            required
          />
          {this.state.eligible && ( //===========> print the state here and change time to see it in working. It will display the check on true and hide on false
            <Input
              name="eligibleAge"
              type="checkbox"
              label="I agree"
              value="unchecked"
            />
          )}
          <Button primary> Submit </Button>
        </Form>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

// <PhoneInput
//  country="US"
//  value={this.phoneNumberValidation.value}
//  onChange={this.phoneNumberValidation.setValue} />
```

working demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-date-checkbox-toggle-o9q2f)